# Если в строке больше 3 элементов тогда заменять на букву "К"

Tags: javascript

Всех приветствую, такая задачка

Написать программу запрашивающая строку. Удалить из строки последние 2 элемента. Заменить в строке буквы "р" на "к", если их больше 3, иначе заменить их на "в"
Моя программа не реагирует на условие больше и выводит всегда переменную less, кто-нибудь может сказать почему? Заранее благодарю

```
let str = prompt("Введите строку");
let newStr = str.slice(0, -2);

if (newStr.indexOf("р") < 3) {
    let less = newStr.replaceAll('р', 'к');
    alert("Буквы 'р' в строке меньше трёх: " + less)
}else {
    let more = newStr.replaceAll('р', 'в');
    alert("Буквы 'р' в строке больше трёх: " + more)
    
}
```

Comment: вы уверены, что `indexOf` вам считает сколько повторов буквы Р в строке?

Comment: @teran
Нет, не уверен, поэтому спрашиваю, что нужно добавить, чтобы просчёт символов ввёлся

Comment: Нужно добавить функцию, считающую количество символов "р" в строке.

Comment: так почему у вас в коде написан этот фрагмент с `newStr.indexOf` для чего вы его вообще написали? просто так или что?

Comment: @teran написал так, как сделал, в принципе понимаю формально, но вот пытаюсь сделать цикл , но не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска вхождений буквы используйте match с флагом g, который будет искать все вхождения буквы в строке

```
let str = prompt("Введите строку");
let newStr = str.slice(0, -2);
let newStrMatches = newStr.match(/р/g);

if (newStrMatches === null || newStrMatches.length < 3) {
    let less = newStr.replaceAll('р', 'к');
    alert("Буквы 'р' в строке меньше трёх: " + less)
} else {
    let more = newStr.replaceAll('р', 'в');
    alert("Буквы 'р' в строке больше трёх: " + more)   
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
const str = 'Друзья добро пожаловать в этот чудный мир'; 

const modificationString = str => {
let count = 0;
let result = '';
  for (const symbol of  str) {
if (symbol === "р"){
count ++;
}
}
for (let i = 0; i < str.length - 2; i++) {
 if(count > 3 && str[i] === "р") {
result += "в";
} else if (count <=3 && str[i] === "р") {
result += "к";
} else {
result += str[i];
}
}
  return result;
}

console.log(modificationString(str));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!!!